# Replace & symbol and combine surrounding strings

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm doing some string cleaning on business names, and I would like to do two things:

1. Replace the ampersand symbol (&) with 'and'.
2. Combine the strings surrounding the &, **but only those elements, not the entire string**

Here is what I've tried to far but the output is not vectorised for some reason.

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
test <- tibble(name = c("brady & frank mortgage bank", "joe and sons deli"))
new <- test %>%
  mutate(clean = paste(str_split(name, "\\s+")[[1]][grep("&|and", str_split(name, "\\s+")[[1]]) - 1], 
                       str_split(name, "\\s+")[[1]][grep("&|and", str_split(name, "\\s+")[[1]]) + 1], sep = "and"))
```

Here is the output of that:

```
  |name                        |clean         |
  |:---------------------------|:-------------|
  |brady & frank mortgage bank |bradyandfrank |
  |joe and sons deli           |bradyandfrank |
```

I know somehow that the `clean` var is referencing the first element but I'm not sure why it's not vectorised.

Here is my desired output:

```
  |name                        |clean         |
  |:---------------------------|:-------------|
  |brady & frank mortgage bank |bradyandfrank |
  |joe and sons deli           |joeandsons    |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `str_split` returns a list with an entry for every string, and with `str_split(name, "\\s+")[[1]]` you always reference the entry for the first string. Therefore you have to map your function to every entry of the list. You could do this with `lapply` or the a `map` function from the `purrr` package:

```
new <- test %>% 
  mutate(clean = purrr::map_chr(name, function(x) {
    paste(str_split(x, "\\s+")[[1]][grep("&|and", str_split(x, "\\s+")[[1]]) - 1], 
          str_split(x, "\\s+")[[1]][grep("&|and", str_split(x, "\\s+")[[1]]) + 1], sep = "and")
  }))

> new
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name                        clean        
  <chr>                       <chr>        
1 brady & frank mortgage bank bradyandfrank
2 joe and sons deli           joeandsons
```

Comment: This worked for my example dataset but unfortunately did not for my real data. `map_chr` fails explicitly when an empty string is returned, which is good, but forced me to use another method. Thanks again for this solution.